# Remove empty lines from file or nested list

Tags: python

I have a csv file I am putting into a empty list, line by line, so the end result is a nested list with each line in a list e.g:

```
[[1.1,2.6,3,0,4.8],[3.5,7.0,8.0]....and so on.....].
```

The problem is at the end of the file are empty strings which end up in the final list like:

```
[[1.1,2.6,3,0,4.8],[3.5,7.0,8.0],['','','','','','','','','']]
```

How do I get rid of these or stop them being appended to the list. They are quite big csv files so I would prefer to stop them being appended to intial list. I feel I am building a extra large list when I probably don't need too, and this may cause memory issues.
Here is code so far:

```
csvfile = open(file_path, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
data_list = []

for row in reader:
    data_list.append(row)
csvfile.close()
i = 0
file_data = []

while i < len(data_list):
    j = 0
    while j < len(data_list[i]):
        try:
            data_list[i][j] = float(data_list[i][j])
        except ValueError:
            pass            
        j += 1
    file_data.append(data_list[i])
    i += 1

print file_data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is at the end of the file are empty strings

You can just decide not to append them:

```
for row in reader:
    if any(row):              # Checks for at least one non-empty field
       data_list.append(row)
```

Here is how the [*any()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) function works:

```
>>> any(['132', '', '456'])
True

>>> any(['', '', ''])
False
```

Comment: Worth noting: Python considers an empty string a "falsy" value. (Definitely would've tripped me up if I didn't know.) ...Although, unless I'm misreading, `row` would be a list of empty strings. Is a list of empty strings considered falsy? It's a non-empty list.

Comment: Yes row is an empty line, so in original csv file it looks like ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,. Therefore ends up in list as ['','','','','']

Comment: Okay, I now understand what you mean by an empty row.  The line is empty -- it just contains a series of delimiters with nothing in them.     In that case, it is easy to filter-out the list of blanks using *filter*.  I've modified the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger surely this should be `if any(row)` ?

Comment: Yep, that would be better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of your code that's easier to understand what you're attempting to do and somewhat more Pythonic.

First to open and read your file, we use the `with` statement so the file is automatically closed, and build a generator to loop over your CSV file only taking rows that contain at least one non-blank column value and converting each element to a float (via a helper function) if possible, otherwise leave it as a string. Then build `data_list` in one statement instead of appending data...

```
with open(file_path) as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    rows = (map(to_float_if_possible, row) for row in csvin if any(row))
    data_list = list(rows)
```

And the helper function is defined as:

```
def to_float_if_possible(text):
    try:
        return float(text)
    except ValueError as e:
        return text
```

By the looks of it you may wish to consider `numpy` or `pandas` when dealing with this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
csvfile = open('C:\\Users\\CBild\\Desktop\\test.txt', 'r')

reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
data_list = []

for row in reader:
    if any(field.strip() for field in row) :
        data_list.append(row)
csvfile.close()

print(data_list)
```

gives

```
>>> 
[['12 2 5'], ['1 5 4']]
```

Indeed, with condition `if any(field.strip() for field in row)`, you treat rows with no character as empty rows also.